# Why is Luboš Motl's reputation stuck at 99,996?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I up-voted a Luboš Motl answer and thought I might be the first to humbly see his score the first to tick over past 100K. But it seems to be stuck on 99,996.

Is there a reason for this?

Maybe the system has gone haywire over a few people thinking the same as me?

Comment: It's the max 200 reputation per day cap, cf. e.g. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6040/2451

Comment: Hah, you weren't the first to try, indeed ;)

Comment: By the way, voting just to see someone exceed a rep threshold is officially a Bad Thing - it falls in the same category of discouraged behavior as serial voting/revenge downvoting. But it's rare enough that we don't make a fuss about it.

Comment: @DavidZ yes, I agree. But it was on an answer that I understood as being right, and I voted on a few other user's questions/answers.

Comment: Sure, I didn't really mean to be accusatory, just kind of putting that out there as a general reminder.

Answer (score 11):

I have to confess I did exactly the same (my apologies to DavidZ) with the same lack of effect. However I see Luboš is now on 100,026 so we have our first 100k user! Congratulations to Luboš (he said through gritted teeth :-).

Comment: You should take comfort in the fact that you are our site's only true [Legend](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary)... For now. A truly remarkable achievement, which I would like to congratulate you for :)